# Trying to display image using jquery based on json values

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I am learning to use ajax and I was trying to get it to load an image depending on the value in the json (sunny loads sun.png etc) but its not working.

Maybe im not understanding the whole 'response'. Anyway am totally stuck - the image displayed is the same image over and over (the cloud one), tried everything for hours, maybe someone can help.

```js
success: function(response)
{
 $('#weather_data').html('');
     var display = '';
     $.each(response.weatherReports,function(index) 
     {
      var condition= response.weatherReports[index].currentConditions;
      if(condition='Sleet')
      {
       var image= '<img src="weather_icons/sleet.png" alt="sleet">';
      }
      if(condition='Cloudy')
      {
       var image= '<img src="weather_icons/cloud.png" alt="cloudy">';
      }
      
      /*"Sunny", "Cloudy", "Sunny and Cloudy" , "Heavy Cloud" , "Rainy" , "Heavy Rain" , "Thunderstorm" , "Sleet" , "Hail", "Snowy"*/
      display+= '<tr><td>' + response.weatherReports[index].city.city_name + '</td>';
      display+= '<td>' + response.weatherReports[index].currentConditions + ' ' + image + '</td>';
      display+= '<td>' + response.weatherReports[index].temperature + '&deg;C </td>';
      display+= '<td>' + response.weatherReports[index].wind.speed + 'mph </td>';
      display+= '<td>' + response.weatherReports[index].wind.direction + '</td>';
      display+= '<td>' + response.weatherReports[index].wind.chillFactor + '</td></tr>';
      });
      $('#weather_table').append(display);
      var image='';
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's troubleshoot together, first add image variable outside the condition and see if it's shown or not (may be the resource is not found).
Then, log in the console the currentConditions property, to see if your IF statement checks for the correct word or not.

Comment: the resource is found, its in a folder. 
response.weatherReports[index].currentConditions = cloudy. one more thing, maybe my understanding of the $.each loop and response thing are messed up

Comment: actually my friend solved it, he told me it was the if statement. it should have been === instead of one =.    so if(condition==='Sleet') is correct